# Using the count function for the original table ignoring the joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Say I have table `Plan` which contains columns `PlanID`, `AccessID` and `AccessName`.

If I wanted to count the number of plans that contain `AccessID` in the `Plan` table then I could do:

```
select AccessName, COUNT(AccessID)
    from Plan
    group by AccessID, AccessName;
```

The output for this is:

[image]

Introducing a second table, Customer, that contains PlanID and other various irrelevant columns. If I wanted to count the number of customers using a plan that has a TypeID I could do:

```
select AccessName, Plan.AccessID, COUNT(AccessID) as AccessPop
    from Plan
    inner join Customer on Plan.PlanID = Customer.PlanID 
    group by Plan.AccessID, Plan.AccessName;
```

The output for this is:

[image]

However if I wanted to do these both in a single query I run into the problem that I cannot count the original number of plans using a AccessID with the join to the customer table.

Some sample data:

[image: Sample Data]

My question is how would I combine both of these into a single query/ select?

Comment: Use `left join Customer` instead of `inner join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select t.AccessName,t.AccessID,totalcnt, AccessPop from
(
select AccessName,AccessID, COUNT(AccessID) as totalcnt
from Plan group by AccessID, AccessName
)t join 
(
select AccessName, Plan.AccessID, COUNT(AccessID) as AccessPop
from Plan inner join Customer on Plan.PlanID = Customer.PlanID 
group by Plan.AccessID, Plan.AccessName
)t1 on t.AccessID=t1.AccessID
```